# Match Alphanumeric column values in R and return matches

Tags: r, match, multiple-columns

I have two columns C1 and C2 that have alphanumeric values. I want to match the last 4 characters between the two columns and display whether a match was found and if so, what the matched value (in C2) was (displayed under C1_Match_V)

```
C1           C2         C1_match    C1_Match_V
LABC4123    CDAI1345    Not Found   NA
KABC1345    BDAIK210    Found       CDAI1345
BJCKK210    JDAB3219    Found       BDAIK210,DAEFK210
RABE1521    DAEFK210    Not Found
```

i.e. compare last 4 characters between C1 and C2 e.g. 4123 in C1 has no match in C2 so "Not Found" but 1345 and K210 have a match in C2 so "found" and the matched value in C2 is entered in "C1_Match_V" as CDAI1345 and BDAIK210.

Also, there could be multiple matches e.g. K210 has two matches in C2 (BDAIK210 and DAEFK210), I would like all of them returned in C1_Match_V.

As you may notice, values in C1/C2 may not always have the same alphabetically part i.e. LABC or KABC (C1) or BDAIK or JDAB (C2) but as long as the last 4 characters match, that is all i care for.

Structure of the columns is mostly 4 alphabets and 4 numbers but some are 5 alphabets and 3 number items too.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your desired result is? Why does `ABC345` and `DAI567`match? They have different numerical parts (`345`  vs. `567`)? And what should be the output in `C1_Match_V` Can you re-phrase your question?

Comment: ABC345 matches since 345 in C1 has a match in C2. The matched value is DAI345 (matches to ABC345). Remember the matching is purely based on numerical part. And value returned should be from C2

Comment: Can there be at most one match? Is the structure of `C1` and `C2` always the same, i.e. two blocks with numeric part being the second?

Comment: You should better think well and be precise about your question and its details before posting.

Comment: sorry - some of these data issues become apparent as you analyze the output.

Comment: Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated ! The description has been amended to include all info related to this question